# ImportError: cannot import name AddTWoIntsResponse

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following a tutorial and where my srv file is AddTwoInts.srv

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
```

and i have created a server.py file under scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

from service_node.srv import AddTwoInts,AddTWoIntsResponse

import rospy
def handle_add_two_inst(req):
    print("Returning [%s + %s = %s]"%(req.a, req.b, (req.a + req.b)))
    return AddTwoIntsResponse(req.a + req.b)
def add_two_ints_server():
    rospy.init_node('add_two_ints_server')
    s= rospy.Service('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts, handle_add_two_ints)
    print("Ready to add two ints.")
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_two_ints_server()
```

after made changes on cmake and package xml and runiing catkin_make

i tried to run the server.py using

rosrun service_node server.py

and i am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akash/catkin_ws/src/service_node/scripts/server.py", line 5, in <module>
    from service_node.srv import AddTwoInts,AddTWoIntsResponse
ImportError: cannot import name AddTWoIntsResponse
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380543/importerror:-cannot-import-name-addtwointsresponse/) by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please pay attention to the error message:

> ```
> ImportError: cannot import name AddTWoIntsResponse
> ```

notice how it says: `AddTWoIntsResponse`.

The name of your service is `AddTwoInts`. The name of the service response type would be `AddTwoIntsResponse`.

Both are with a lower-case `w`. You wrote it with an uppercase `W`:

```
from service_node.srv import AddTwoInts,AddTWoIntsResponse
```

Just as in your previous question (#q380524) such details are important. Capitalisation of characters matters, as `w` is different from `W`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1